# build daemon disappeared unexpectedly in android studios

Tags: android

I have my android studio on a external hard drive and awhile ago I got "Error:Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)" after killing android studios with the task manager. I could not figure out how to fix the problem so I just switched laptops which fixed the problem. Now android froze on me and I was forced to kill it through task manager again. Now I am getting the same error. The answers on the internet seem vary vague and or not solutions for a beginner like myself.

Comment: You should come back when you have a replicable problem and some screenshots and logs. Until then, there is not much anybody can do.

Comment: I have the one and only log in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding "org.gradle.daemon=false" into my «USER_HOME»/.gradle/gradle.properties, where «USER_HOME» is the home directory.

Comment: I don't have such type of directory on my machine ..What shall I do ..Please reply.

Comment: Go to the project directory. 

For example if your project is called 'MyApplication' the home directory would be called 'MyApplication'.

Answer (score 0):

Just close all the instances of Android Studio and restart your project, it will figure out as it may be because of memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me

```
 org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
Adding org.gradle.daemon=false (or true) to gradle.properties  didn't help.
I changed "home user directory for gradle" in Android studio settings to other (new) directory. After that "Sync project" and Gradle started and synced successfully.